# create a variable in a dataframe based on another matrix on R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector

I am having some problems with the following task
I have a data frame of this type with 99 different countries for thousands of IDs

```
   ID  Nationality  var 1 var 2 ....
    1  Italy         //
    2  Eritrea       //
    3  Italy        //
    4  USA
    5  France
    6  France
    7  Eritrea
    ....
```

I want to add a variable corresponding to a given macroregion of  Nationality
so I created a matrix of this kind with the rule to follow

```
Nationality Continent
Italy       Europe
Eritrea     Africa
Usa         America
France      Europe
Germany     Europe
....
```

I d like to obtain this

```
        ID  Nationality  var 1 var 2 Continent
        1  Italy         //          Europe   
        2  Eritrea       //          Africa
        3  Italy        //           Europe
        4  USA                       America
        5  France                    Europe
        6  France                    Europe
        7  Eritrea                   Africa
        ....
```

I was trying with this command

```
datasubset <- merge(dataset , continent.matrix )
```

but it doesn't work, it reports the following error
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 56.6 Mb

that seems very strange to me, also trying to apply this code to a subset it doesn't work. do you have any suggestion on how to proceed?

thank you very much in advance for your help, I hope my question doesn't sound too trivial, but I am quite new to R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `left_join` function (dplyr's library):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(ID=c(1,2,3),
             Nationality=c("Italy", "Usa", "France"),
             var1=c("a", "b", "c"),
             var2=c(4,5,6))

nat_cont <- tibble(Nationality=c("Italy", "Eritrea", "Usa", "Germany", "France"),
                   Continent=c("Europe", "Africa", "America", "Europe", "Europe"))


df_2 <- left_join(df, nat_cont, by=c("Nationality"))
```

The output:

```
> df_2
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID Nationality var1   var2 Continent
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr> <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 Italy       a         4 Europe   
2     2 Usa         b         5 America  
3     3 France      c         6 Europe
```